# Add extra html tags to jquery-ui-accordion section

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("body").show();
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    header: '> div.my-accordion-section > h3',
    heightStyle: 'content'
});
```

});

I would like to add another html tag after the h3 as a subtitle within the header, how would I write it? I tried 
    `header: '> div.my-accordion-section > h3, p',`

It did not work with or without the comma after the h3

Comment: Thanks for answering - the html is `<div id="accordion">
 <div class="my-accordion-section">
  <h3>Header 1</h3>
  <div>
   Ut gravida lobortis diam non varius. Duis tempor cursus justo ut consequat. Donec bibendum sem arcu, at placerat orci ultricies sed. 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="my-accordion-section">
  <h3>Header 2</h3>
  <div>
   Praesent iaculis lacus quis elementum vulputate. 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="my-accordion-section">
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <div>
   Phasellus ligula eros, interdum et posuere ut, dapibus ac tortor. 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the `header` option works. If you want the subtitle just to be smaller than the title, try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Header 1 <span>Subtitle 1</span></h3>
    <div> Ut gravida lobortis diam non varius. Duis tempor cursus justo ut consequat. Donec bibendum sem arcu, at placerat orci ultricies sed. </div>
    <h3>Header 2 <span>Subtitle 2</span></h3>
    <div> Praesent iaculis lacus quis elementum vulputate. </div>          
    <h3>Header 3 <span>Subtitle 3</span></h3>
    <div> Phasellus ligula eros, interdum et posuere ut, dapibus ac tortor. </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#accordion h3 span{
    font-size: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle
}
#accordion h3 span:before{
    content: "- ";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptrK5/

Comment: Thank you, I already tried span tags, but maybe my css is not targeting properly. I will take a fresh look tomorrow.

Comment: That doesn't work, the css doesn't even appear in a web inspector. Take a look it's a very messy test site. http://marazuldelsur.com/wordpress/about/

Comment: Got it, a css error as I thought. Thank you for your help.